# Swashbuckle request parameters not working when using custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API endpoint configured as follows:

```
[HttpGet("api/controller/action/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingle([FromRoute] GetSingleRequest request) {...}
```

The DTO has a single Guid property:

```
public class GetSingleRequest
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured a custom model binder to bind Guid properties to string values as I'm using a short guid implementation. This is all working fine when testing using Postman.

However, when using Swagger, instead of passing the route parameter as entered, it passes the parameter template, E.g.

```
GET /api/controller/action/{id}     // Literally constructs the URI with {id}
GET /api/controller/action/abcd1234 // Not the value as entered
```

I have tried using `MapType` and `ISchemaFilter` as follows:

```
// startup.cs
c.MapType<Guid>(() => new OpenApiSchema {Type = "string", Format = null});
```

```
// startup.cs
c.SchemaFilter<GuidSchemaFilter>();

// GuidSchemaFilter.cs
internal class GuidSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
  {
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
      if (context.Type != typeof(Guid))
      {
        return;
      }

      schema.Type = "string";
      schema.Format = null;
    }
  }
```

Neither of these approaches change this odd behaviour.

**How can I configure Swagger to pass a string instead of a Guid as part of the URI when I have a custom model binder configured?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I configure Swagger to pass a string instead of a Guid as part
> of the URI when I have a custom model binder configured?

In fact,  `c.MapType<Guid>(() => new OpenApiSchema {Type = "string", Format = null});` this sentence is enough to solve the problem.

The key to the problem is that the parameters in your route are `Camel Case`: **id**, and the field in the GetSingleRequest is the `Pascal Case`: **Id**.

As the comment, you can add `c.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();` to make it ignore the problem of case.

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API" });
                c.MapType<Guid>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = null });
                c.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
            });
```

**Or you change the id in the route template to Id**.

```
        [HttpGet("api/controller/action/{Id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingle([FromRoute] GetSingleRequest request) 
        {

            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]